# OnClick button navigates to dashboard instead of new fragment

Tags: android

I have a device specific issue in my android application. image icon onclick a new fragment should get loaded but instead it navigates to Dashboard. It is working fine on all the other devices except Samsung duos devices.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.add_deal:
            Intent addDealIntent = new Intent(mContext, BaseFragmentActivity.class);
            addDealIntent.putExtra("Merchant", merchantInfo);
            addDealIntent.putExtra("FragmentClassName", AddDealFragment.class.getName());
            addDealIntent.putExtra("toolbarTitle", "Add Deal");
            mContext.startActivity(addDealIntent);
            break;
        case R.id.add_product:
            Intent addProductIntent = new Intent(mContext, BaseFragmentActivity.class);
            addProductIntent.putExtra("Merchant", merchantInfo);
            addProductIntent.putExtra("Categories", mMerchantCategories);
            addProductIntent.putExtra("SubCategories", mMerchantSubCategories);
            addProductIntent.putExtra("SubSubCategories", mMerchantSubSubCategories);
            addProductIntent.putExtra("SuperSubCategories", mMerchantSuperSubCategories);
            addProductIntent.putExtra("FragmentClassName", AddProductFragment.class.getName());
            addProductIntent.putExtra("toolbarTitle", "Add Product");
            mContext.startActivity(addProductIntent);
            break;
        case R.id.dialog_button_cancel:
            dismiss();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
     dismiss();
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and wrap all that inside the code tag. use ` `

Comment: need some more explanation. is it working fine rest devices ? your xml layout structure.

Comment: Yes it is working absolutely fine on all the other devices except Samsung duos devices.

Answer (score 0):

With startActivity method you can only navigate between activitis then you must change fragment.

You can use this code to change your fragments :

```
// Create new fragment and transaction
Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack if needed
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: I tried using this solution but the still same problem is occuring

Comment: I tried the code but then it still navigates to the same page